# vb.net WMI query to string

Tags: wmi-query

I have a little issue with WMI query.
I have to check if a certain property exists in a WMI query instance, the code i have done is:

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Management.Instrumentation

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim search_cpu As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
        Dim info_cpu As ManagementObject '= Convert.ToUInt32("search_cpu")
        Dim cpu_v As Integer
        For Each info_cpu In search_cpu.Get()
            If search_cpu.Get("caption") = True Then
                cpu_v = "Caption"
                Label1.Text = ("Name: " & info_cpu(cpu_v).ToString())
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the matter exactly?

Comment: It gives me an error of convertion to integer.
System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Please take some time to review your question and fix the formatting issues.

Comment: I think that the formating issues are fixed, the question is:

Comment: I think that the formating issues are fixed, the question is:
I have to check if a determining WMI query is true or false, if true it runs the query, if false it does not run the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce. The below code works allright for me and Label1 now displays:

**Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9**

```
    Sub Main()
            Dim search_cpu As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
            Dim info_cpu As ManagementObject '= Convert.ToUInt32("search_cpu")
            Dim caption As String
            For Each info_cpu In search_cpu.Get()
                caption = info_cpu("caption").ToString()
            Next
            Label1.Text = caption
            if (string.isnullorempty(caption))
            Label1.Text ="<does not exist>"
        End Sub
```